# unicodecsv reader from unicode string not working?

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I'm having trouble reading in a unicode CSV string into python-unicodescv:

```
>>> import unicodecsv, StringIO
>>> f = StringIO.StringIO(u'é,é')
>>> r = unicodecsv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8')
>>> row = r.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/guy/test/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unicodecsv/__init__.py", line 101, in next
    row = self.reader.next()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm guessing it's an issue with how I convert my unicode string into a StringIO file somehow? The example on the python-unicodecsv github page works fine:

```
>>> import unicodecsv
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> f = StringIO()
>>> w = unicodecsv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8')
>>> w.writerow((u'é', u'ñ'))
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> r = unicodecsv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8')
>>> row = r.next()
>>> print row[0], row[1]
é ñ
```

Trying my code with cStringIO fails as cStringIO can't accept unicode (so why the example works, I don't know!)

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> f = StringIO(u'é')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm need to accept a UTF-8 CSV formatted input from a web textarea form field, hence can't just read in from a file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `unicodecsv` file reads and decodes **byte strings** for you. You are passing it `unicode` strings instead. On output, your unicode values are encoded to bytestrings for you, using the configured codec.

In addition, `cStringIO.StringIO` can only handle encoded bytestrings, while the pure-python `StringIO.StringIO` class happily treats `unicode` values as if they are byte strings.

The solution is to *encode* your unicode values before putting them into the `StringIO` object:

```
>>> import unicodecsv, StringIO, cStringIO
>>> f = StringIO.StringIO(u'é,é'.encode('utf8'))
>>> r = unicodecsv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8')
>>> next(r)
[u'\xe9', u'\xe9']
>>> f = cStringIO.StringIO(u'é,é'.encode('utf8'))
>>> r = unicodecsv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8')
>>> next(r)
[u'\xe9', u'\xe9']
```

Comment: Excellent. Great answer and quick. gotta love SO :)