# unicode encoding error using unicodecsv

Tags: python, csv, unicode, utf-8

I write a list into a csv file using unicodecsv module, encoding it by "utf-8", but when I try to read it using unicodecsv.reader, I still get the error:`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte...`. I can read it in by csv.reader. Is there something that I am missing?

My codes are like this:

```
    with open(datapath + filename, 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer_to_csv = unicodecsv.writer(csvfile, encoding = "utf-8")
        writer_to_csv.writerows(data)
```

When I try to read it:

```
   with open(datapath + filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        file_to_list = unicodecsv.reader(csvfile, encoding = "utf-8")
```

I got the error message.

Comment: What does `data` look like?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479589/unicodecsv-reader-from-unicode-string-not-working ?

Comment: @SimeonVisser, thanks. I saw that answer, but I already encoded the data in ``utf8``, that's why I don't understand the problem. Moreover, if I use csv.reader in the second part, it works with no problem. Is there anything special about ``unicodecsv`` that I am missing here? The data are parsed from a large xml file, just for your information.

Comment: If it can't read the file as UTF-8 then perhaps it isn't written properly as UTF-8. So although you get the error when reading the real error may happen when writing. So that's why I'm thinking you may be writing `data` incorrectly and it doesn't have the type/format that `writer_to_csv.writerows` expects.

Comment: @SimeonVisser, I think you are right. I can use encoding = "ISO 8859-1" to read the data. So I cannot really forcefully to write the data as "utf8" encoded?

Comment: If the data is currently encoded in ISO 8859-1 then you'll need to decode it to Unicode first and then encode the data to UTF-8 when passing it to write. However, I'm not sure whether that is possible so you may need to use ISO 8859-1 for both writing and reading.