# 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' in python with unicodecsv

Tags: python

The following code gives an error in python 3.8,  with networkx, unicodecsv

```
with open('hero-network.csv', 'r') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    **for row in reader:**
        graph.add_edge(*row)
```

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: It's not clear what is throwing this error. Can you include the entire stack trace, as well as what `graph` is?

Comment: What happens if you use the regular Python `csv` module instead of `unicodecsv`? Bear in mind that `unicodecsv` was designed to get around shortcomings in Python *2.7*, but that error message looks like it's from Python *3*.

Comment: @jjramsey It is working with regular csv module. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`unicodescv.reader` expects a file opened in *binary* mode, because, in theory at least, it is going to work out how to decode the bytes.

```
with open('hero-network.csv', 'rb') as data:   # the mode is 'rb', not 'r'
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        graph.add_edge(*row)
```

As pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61279985/str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-in-python-with-unicodecsv/61288098#comment108408425_61279985) by [jramsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1643973/jjramsey), `unicodecsv` is more useful for Python2, when the standard library's csv module's unicode handling was poor.  In Python 3 you can specify an encoding when you open the file and pass the resulting file object to the standard library's csv module.

Answer (score 0):

`reader` method in `csv` accept a `reader` not a `str`.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21479663/13334490).

Answer (score 0):

That error happens when you try to decode a `str` that is already decoded. Are you passing the parameters correctly?

Source: ['str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Python 3 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583565/str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-python-3-error)